# PHP: Create array out of XML string

Tags: php, arrays, xml

I want to make an array of players sorted in order of salary from the following XML. Notice that I already sort the basketball teams by salary.

```
<?php
$string = <<<EOS
<Sports_Team>
<Basketball>
<Players>Tom, Jack, Sue</Players>
<salary>4</salary>
</Basketball>
<Basketball>
<Players>Josh, Lee, Carter, Bennett</Players>
<salary>6</salary>
</Basketball>
<Basketball>
<Players>Mary, Jimmy, Nancy</Players>
<salary>44</salary>
</Basketball>
</Sports_Team>
EOS;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);

$trees = $xml->xpath('/Sports_Team/Basketball');

function sort_trees($t1, $t2) {
    return strcmp($t1['salary'], $t2['salary']);
}

usort($trees, 'sort_trees');
var_dump($trees);
?>
```

I want to make an array of Players from `$trees`. How do I create an array object such that:

```
[0]-> Mary, Jimmy, Nancy
[1]-> Josh, Lee, Carter, Bennett
[2]-> Tom, Jack, Sue
```

Also, once I've stored my array how do I print it out visually?

Comment: I fixed one problem in my first example; `$users` was used instead of `$trees`. I also answered a part about sorting by number of players :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you have done everything perfectly right, except a couple of tiny bits which i will address bellow :)

- In your user-defined comparison function 'sort_trees', best to compare integer directly and not the string, so no need to compare string using (strcmp).
- Also you could use `uasort()` method instead of `usort()` to maintain index association

so your code with a tiny change can be something like the following, and finally I'm using `print_r()` method to print the array as you asked

```
<?php

function sort_trees_by_salary($t1, $t2)
{
    return (int)$t1['salary'] > (int)$t2['salary'];
}


function sort_trees_by_number_of_players($t1, $t2)
{
    return substr_count($t1->Players, ',') > substr_count($t2->Players, ',');
}


$string = <<<EOS
<Sports_Team>
<Basketball>
<Players>Tom, Jack, Sue</Players>
<salary>4</salary>
</Basketball>
<Basketball>
<Players>Josh, Lee, Carter, Bennett</Players>
<salary>6</salary>
</Basketball>
<Basketball>
<Players>Mary, Jimmy, Nancy</Players>
<salary>44</salary>
</Basketball>
</Sports_Team>
EOS;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);

$trees = $xml->xpath('/Sports_Team/Basketball');

// Lets say you want to sort by salary
uasort($trees, 'sort_trees_by_salary');
$results = [];
foreach ($trees as $tree) {
    $results[] = (string)$tree->Players;
}

echo 'Sorted by Salary:';
print_r($results);


// Lets say you want to sort by number of players
uasort($trees, 'sort_trees_by_number_of_players');
$results = [];
foreach ($trees as $tree) {
    $results[] = (string)$tree->Players;
}

echo 'Sorted by number of players:';
print_r($results);
```

Output:

```
Sorted by Salary:Array
(
    [0] => Mary, Jimmy, Nancy
    [1] => Josh, Lee, Carter, Bennett
    [2] => Tom, Jack, Sue
)
Sorted by number of players:Array
(
    [0] => Mary, Jimmy, Nancy
    [1] => Tom, Jack, Sue
    [2] => Josh, Lee, Carter, Bennett
)
```

**Please note:** considering the [user-defined comparison function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php)  works with the reference the above example will apply both sorting methods on your set of data, first to order the list based on the salary and second based on the number players

Comment: How would I create a sorted array by the number of players?

Comment: @cooldood3490, I have included a solution to sort your list based on the number of players according to the number of commas (,) found in each row. however the best approach  is to include the number of players in your xml dataset. but that only is possible if you have access to the data source/provider as well.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have PHP 5.3+, try this:

```
$playersArray = array_map(
    create_function('$inputArray', 'return (string) $inputArray->Players;'),
    $trees
);
```

For example:

```
php > var_dump($playersArray);
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(18) "Mary, Jimmy, Nancy"
  [1]=>
  string(26) "Josh, Lee, Carter, Bennett"
  [2]=>
  string(14) "Tom, Jack, Sue"
}
```

If you're using older PHP, you need to use a real (non-anonymous) function for `array_map()`, or use `create_function()`:

```
$playersArray = array_map(
    create_function('$inputArray', 'return (array) $inputArray->Players;'),
    $users
);
```

To answer the last part, how do you print it out visually, well, that depends! If you just want to dump it to view it for debugging purposes, use `var_dump()` or `print_r()`. Both take the array variable as the only needed argument. `var_dump()` is a bit more verbose.

This is `var_dump()` ([manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php)):

```
php > var_dump($playersArray);
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(18) "Mary, Jimmy, Nancy"
  [1]=>
  string(26) "Josh, Lee, Carter, Bennett"
  [2]=>
  string(14) "Tom, Jack, Sue"
}
```

This is `print_r()` ([manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php)):

```
php > print_r($playersArray);
Array
(
    [0] => Mary, Jimmy, Nancy
    [1] => Josh, Lee, Carter, Bennett
    [2] => Tom, Jack, Sue
)
```

Otherwise, to process and display output for end users based on the array, you'll likely want to loop through it and process it, or use `array_map()` similarly to above to generate the output. Also, if you want to experiment with this in a [PHP Console](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.interactive.php) similarly to what I did in my examples, you can run `php -a` and type your code at the prompt.

**Edit**

To answer the question from the comments, try this:

```
/* Sort by the number of ',' characters in the string. */
function sort_players($a, $b) {
    $ca = substr_count($a, ',');
    $cb = substr_count($b, ',');
    if ($ca == $cb) return 0;
    return ($ca > $cb) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($playersArray, 'sort_players');
```

Comment: Please do not use `create_function` without static caching. That creates global functions for each calls, those are **never disposed**.

Comment: Simple Wrapper: `function create_func($arg, $code) { static $c; if (!isset($c[$arg][$code])) $c[$arg][$code] = create_function($arg, $code); return $c[$arg][$code]; }`